# Get an image from drive which is inserted into a cell in google sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api, gspread

the cell looks like this:

```
=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=10xr_wqpuawMFHI1Y0kPY")
```

when i try
data = worksheet.get_all_values()
the cell that contains the image(url) is empty

```
def upload_image(image_path):
    """Uploads an image to Google Drive and returns the file ID."""
    file_metadata = {
        'name': os.path.basename(image_path),
        'mimeType': 'image/png'
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(image_path, mimetype='image/png', resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    file_id = file.get('id')

    return file_id
```

```
# Insert image to Google Sheets
            insert_image = f'=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={image_id}")'
            cell_ref = rowcol_to_a1(row, 1)  # convert row and column number to cell notation
            sheet.update(cell_ref, insert_image, value_input_option='USER_ENTERED')
```

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Get an image` of `Get an image from drive which is inserted into a cell in google sheets` and your current issue. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi using `gspread` you can't get the actual image.

The way google spreadsheets works is:

- you set a formula that specifies the image URL
- when using your web browser it sees the formula and then pulls the image to display it on the web browser
- when using gpsread the data is simply not return as it has no actual value
- when using gspread you can request the data and ask for the special format that returns the formula of a given cell range, which will return the formula with the `=IMAGE(....)`.
- then you can extract the link and pull the image manually if you need it.